# mass file encryption not working with openssl

Tags: logs, encryption, openssl

I have bunch of log files which I am trying to encrypt with public/private key using openssl and save to my NAS but it is failing.

My log files are in the following path :

```
/var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive
```

My public key and private key are in `/etc/log-enc/`

```
[root@NAG01 log-enc]# ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 891 Jul 11 15:58 syslog_privalye_key.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 272 Jul 11 15:59 syslog_public_key.pem
```

Now I am trying to execute following command
If I am executing the same command one by one, then there is no issue.

```
for file in `find /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/`
do  
FILE_BASE=$(basename $file)
echo "$file=>/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$FILE_BASE.enc"
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey  /etc/log-enc/syslog_public_key.pem -pubin -in $file -out /NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$FILE_BASE.enc
done
```

Here are the error logs

```
RSA operation error
140628568049480:error:0406D06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2:data too large for key size:rsa_pk1.c:151:
/var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/192.168.33.5.log-20160131.gz=>/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/192.168.33.5.log-20160131.gz.enc
RSA operation error
140123978278728:error:0406D06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2:data too large for key size:rsa_pk1.c:151:
/var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/app02.log-20160306.gz=>/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/app02.log-20160306.gz.enc
/var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/192.168.34.8.log-20160227.gz=>/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/192.168.34.8.log-20160227.gz.enc
RSA operation error
139777258493768:error:0406D06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_type_2:data too large for key size:rsa_pk1.c:151:
/var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/192.168.31.3.log-20160511.gz=>/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/192.168.31.3.log-20160511.gz.enc
```

Here are the raw files.

```
[root@NAG01 log-enc]# ls -l /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/192.168.33.5.log-20160131.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root 3569 Jan 31 04:16 /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/192.168.33.5.log-20160131.gz
[root@NAG01 log-enc]# ls -l /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/192.168.34.8.log-20160227.gz
-rw-------. 1 root root 2142 Feb 27 03:11 /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/192.168.34.8.log-20160227.gz
```

Comment: `openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey  /etc/log-enc/syslog_privalye_key.pem -in $file -out /NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$FILE_BASE.enc`

Comment: no it is still not working @SatoKatsura

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: @Rahul, i am not using any ssl certificate

Comment: @SatoKatsura, still same error

Comment: Did you also drop `-pubin`?  Your input files are not public keys.

Comment: for file in `find /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/` do  FILE_BASE=$(basename $file); echo "$file=>/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$FILE_BASE.enc" openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey /etc/log-enc/syslog_private_key.pem -in $file -out /NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$FILE_BASE.enc done

Comment: i have to use public key or private key ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42306/discussion-between-suyash-jain-and-sato-katsura).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

First create the keys

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private-key.pem -out public-key.pem
```

then the same loop

```
for file in `find /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/`
do 
FILE_BASE=$(basename $file)
echo "$file=>/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$FILE_BASE.enc"
openssl smime -encrypt -binary -aes-256-cbc -in  $file -out /NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$FILE_BASE.enc -outform DER public-key.pem

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `openssl` to encrypt files. It's not designed for this. (`openssl` isn't really *designed* for anything.) You're just fumbling in the dark. In the tiger's cage.

[GnuPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) is designed precisely to encrypt files. Install it from your distribution. Use `gpg --gen-key` to generate a new key. The keys are stored in `~/.gnupg`. Use `gpg --export` to export a public key from an account, `gpg --export-secret-keys` to export a secret key, and `gpg --import` to import it on another acccount.

To encrypt a file, use `gpg -e /path/to/file`. To decrypt, use `gpg /path/to/file.gpg`.

---

[Don't parse the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters), use `find … -exec …`. And always use double quotes around variable and command substitutions. Maybe your files don't have special characters now, but using double quotes can't cause any harm and will save you from a security breach one day.

Your script is also broken in other ways, such as attempting to encrypt directories, causing spurious errors. From the look of your script, it looks like you don't expect to find subdirectories in `/var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/`, in which case you don't need `find`.

```
cd /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/ &&
for x in *; do
  gpg -e -o "/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$x.gpg" "$x"
done
```

If there are subdirectories:

```
cd /var/SYSLOGS/hosts/archive/ &&
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
  mkdir -p "${0%/*}" &&
  gpg -e -o "/NFS/Nag01/syslogs/hosts/$0.gpg" "$0"
'
```